# Retrieve CheckboxList values from Database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, checkboxlist

I have tried codes from here and there from all over the place but couldnt get anything to work...

I have my CheckBoxList values saved in a database. All i want is to Retrieve the values from Database and get the CheckBox List items to be selected accordingly.

The code in design page is:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Sales</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">Office & Administration</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">Domestic Help</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="4">Education & Training</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="5">Accounting and Finance</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="6">Hospitality and Tourism</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="7">Computer and IT</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="8">Customer Service</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="9">Logistics and Transportation</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="10">Healthcare</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="11">Food and Beverage</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="12">Marketing, Media & Communication</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="13">Construction & Architecture</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="14">Human Resources</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="15">Others</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

So i use this code to save the CheckBoxList values into the database. **WHICH WORKS FINE...**

```
 for (int j = 0; j < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        if (CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Selected == true)
        {
            string r = CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Value.ToString();
            SqlConnection myconn1;
            SqlCommand cmd1;
            string sql1;
            myconn1 = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());
            myconn1.Open();
            sql1 = "insert into interests(FK_ic_id,FK_is_id)values(@FK_ic_id,@FK_is_id)";
            cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, myconn1);

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_is_id", ssid);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_ic_id", r);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myconn1.Close();
        }
    }
```

So the table is 'interests', there is a seperate table for category names (list of interests). The data is saved like:

- User-1 (FK_IS_ID), Interest-2 (FK_IC_ID)
- User-1 (FK_IS_ID), Interest-3 (FK_IC_ID)
- User-2 (FK_IS_ID), Interest-4 (FK_IC_ID)
- User-2 (FK_IS_ID), Interest-2 (FK_IC_ID)

The interest 2-3 indicates the interest from the 'category' table, which has :

- category-1(c_id), Sales (c_name)
- category-2(c_id), Marketing (c_name)
- category-3(c_id), IT (c_name)

So now all i want is, on page load function the checkbox list to be repopulated, or filled depending on the user (SID) and his interests(c_id/FK_IC_ID). The items in checkboxlist needs to be selected on page load function. There needs to be multiple interests retrieved.

Comment: I dunno, im new to asp.net...
But that question is related to dropdownlist, which has no complicated stuff like the loop, the indexes etc like in the CheckBoxList

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your checklistbox to a datasource:

```
    SqlDataAdapter da = 
            new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT c_id,c_name FROM category",
            new SqlConnection
           (WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
           ["ApplicationServices"].ToString())); 
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            checkedListBox1.DataSource = ds;
            checkedListBox1.SelectedValue = "c_id";
            checkedListBox1.SelectedItem = "c_name ";
```

Comment: Im really sorry, im new to this stuff...
What does the AccountM indicate? and we dont use loop in the retrieval? as multiple interest can be there for 1 user..

Comment: You're very welcome bro, I really didn't get you well, can you please bring the structure of your **User** and **category** table?

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt really clear..
What i meant was, for example if there is 2 users, SID=1 and SID=2...
So if SID 1 checks value 2,3,5 on checkbox, it is saved in interest table like:
- interestID=1, SID=1, c_id=2
<next entry in table>- interestID=2, SID=1, c_id=3
<next entry in table>- interestID=3, SID=1, c_id=5

So now when i load the page i want the the checkbox list to have 2,3,5 marked if SID=1.

Comment: So I think you should have some joins in the select command of SQLDataAdapter between **Users,Interests and categories**

Comment: Could you post the code for that? Just leave the user part.. think there is just 1 user... and its static.. so i just need interest and categories to be joined.. When i try ur code, SelectedItem is giving me an error.

Comment: I'm really sorry while I don't know the structure of your tables I can't write the query, But I think this code should work. you have to go through your codes more and more, I hope you'll solve it, it's nothing. good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)

Just let me know what AccountM means and why im getting an error on SelectedItem...

Comment: I'm sorry for it, I was in hurry, it was table name in dataset and it's not need, you can remove it, I removed it

Comment: you can also use **checkedListBox1.DataSource = ds.tables[0];**

Comment: Nothing seems to happen, no errors but nothing is checked on pageload as well